# Python Implementation of Folder Directory in Console

Tags: python, recursion, directory, directory-structure

I am given an array of arrays in which I am to simulate a folder system based off of the given. For example:

```
Given = [[('folder1',), 'file1'], [('folder2',), 'file2', [('folder3',), 'file3', 'file4']]]
```

The output should be:

```
folder1
└───file1
folder2
├───file2
└───folder3
    ├───file3
    └───file4
```

Folders are identified as the first of every array, and they are in tuples, while files are just strings inside the arrays.

I have an initial code but it's not outputting the the right result. There are mistakes in generating `├───`, `└───`, etc. How do we recursively implement this?

Here's my code:

```
arrayOfArrays = [[('folder1',), 'file1'], [('folder2',), 'file2', [('folder3',), 'file3', 'file4']]]
def sChar(indent):                        # Creates the indentation and
    if indent > 1:                        # Special Characters
        print("│", end='')
        while indent != 1:
            print("   ", end='')
            indent-=1
    if indent == 1:
        print("├───", end='')
        
def folderDirectory(directory, indent = 0):
    for i in range(len(directory)):
        if isinstance(directory[i], tuple):
            sChar(indent)
            print(directory[i][0])
            indent+=1
        elif isinstance(directory[i], list):
            folderDirectory(directory[i], indent)
        else:
            sChar(indent)
            print(directory[i])
            
folderDirectory(arrayOfArrays)
```

Actual Output:

```
folder1
├───file1
folder2
├───file2
├───folder3
│   ├───file3
│   ├───file4
```

Test Case 2:

```
Given: [('folder1',), [('folder2',), 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6', 'file7'], 'file8', 'file9', [('folder3',), 'file10', 'file11', 'file12'], 'file13']
```

Expected Output:

```
folder1
├───folder2
│   ├───file1
│   ├───file2
│   ├───file3
│   ├───file4
│   ├───file5
│   ├───file6
│   └───file7
├───file8
├───file9
├───folder3
│   ├───file10
│   ├───file11
│   └───file12
└───file13
```

Test Case 3:

```
Given: [[('folder1',)], [('folder2',), [('folder3',), 'file2', 'file3']], [('folder4',), [('folder5',), 'file4']]]
```

Expected:

```
folder1
folder2
└───folder3
    ├───file3
    └───file2
folder4
└───folder5
    └───file4
```

Test Case 4:

```
Given: [('folder1',), [('folder2',), [('folder3',), 'file2', 'file3']], [('folder3',), [('folder4',), 'file4', 'file5']]]
```

Expected:

```
folder1
├───folder2
│   └───folder3
│       ├───file2
│       └───file3
└───folder3
    └───folder4
        ├───file4
        └───file5
```

Worst Case (Folders are placed before files, depth of 10)

```
[('f01',), [('f02',), [('f03',), [('f04',), [('f05',), [('f06',), [('f07',), [('f08',), [('f09',), [('f10',), 'g09', 'g10'], 'g08'], 'g07'], 'g06'], 'g05'], 'g04'], 'g03'], 'g02'], 'g01'], [('f11',), 'g11']]

f01
├───f02
│   ├───f03
│   │   ├───f04
│   │   │   ├───f05
│   │   │   │   ├───f06
│   │   │   │   │   ├───f07
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├───f08
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├───f09
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├───f10
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├───g09
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   └───g10
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   └───g08
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └───g07
│   │   │   │   │   │   └───g06
│   │   │   │   │   └───g05
│   │   │   │   └───g04
│   │   │   └───g03
│   │   └───g02
│   └───g01
└───f11
    └───g11
```

You can use this code to use the special characters

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

**Latest code (Works!)**

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

def lister(directory, ind=0, f = True):
    yield f'{(("    "*(ind-1)) if not f else "")}{"" if not ind else ""*(ind-1)+("" if f else "└")+"───"}'+directory[0][0]
    for i, a in enumerate(directory[1:]):
        if isinstance(a, str):
            yield f'{(("    "*(ind)) if not f else "") + ("└" if i == len(directory[1:]) - 1 else "├")+"───"}'+a
        else:
            for k in lister(a, ind=ind+1, f= i + 1 != len(directory[1:])):
                yield ('│' if not k.startswith("─") else "├") +("" if k.startswith("───") else '   ' if not k.startswith('   ') else '')+k if i + 1 != len(directory[1:]) else k
                
def get_results(s):
  for i in ([s] if isinstance(s[0], tuple) else s):
     print('\n'.join(lister(i)))
     
data = [('f01',), [('f02',), [('f03',), [('f04',), [('f05',), [('f06',), [('f07',), [('f08',), [('f09',), [('f10',), 'g09', 'g10'], 'g08'], 'g07'], 'g06'], 'g05'], 'g04'], 'g03'], 'g02'], 'g01'], [('f11',), 'g11']]
get_results(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly tweak your recursion and use ascii characters `└`, `│` and `─`:

```
import re
def get_struct(folder, ind=0, f = True):
   yield f'{(("    "*(ind-1)) if not f else "")}{"" if not ind else ""*(ind-1)+("" if f else "└")+"───"}'+folder[0][0]
   for i, a in enumerate(folder[1:]):
     if isinstance(a, str):
        yield f'{(("    "*(ind)) if not f else "") + ("└" if i == len(folder[1:]) - 1 else "│")+"───"}'+a
     else:
        for k in get_struct(a, ind=ind+1, f= i + 1 != len(folder[1:])):
          yield '│'+("" if k.startswith("───") else '    ' if not k.startswith('    ') else '')+k if i + 1 != len(folder[1:]) else k

def get_results(s):
  for i in ([s] if isinstance(s[0], tuple) else s):
     print('\n'.join(get_struct(i)))

data = [('f01',), [('f02',), [('f03',), [('f04',), [('f05',), [('f06',), [('f07',), [('f08',), [('f09',), [('f10',), 'g09', 'g10'], 'g08'], 'g07'], 'g06'], 'g05'], 'g04'], 'g03'], 'g02'], 'g01'], [('f11',), 'g11']]

get_results(data)
data1 = [('folder1',), [('folder2',), [('folder3',), 'file2', 'file3']], [('folder3',), [('folder4',), 'file4', 'file5']]]
get_results(data1)
data2 = [('folder1',), [('folder2',), 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6', 'file7'], 'file8', 'file9', [('folder3',), 'file10', 'file11', 'file12'], 'file13']
get_results(data2)
data3 = [[('folder1',), 'file1', [('folder1',), 'file1']], [('folder2',), 'file2', [('folder3',), 'file3', 'file4']]]
get_results(data3)
```

Output(1):

```
f01
│───f02
│    │───f03
│    │    │───f04
│    │    │    │───f05
│    │    │    │    │───f06
│    │    │    │    │    │───f07
│    │    │    │    │    │    │───f08
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    │───f09
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │───f10
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │───g09
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    └───g10
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    │    └───g08
│    │    │    │    │    │    │    └───g07
│    │    │    │    │    │    └───g06
│    │    │    │    │    └───g05
│    │    │    │    └───g04
│    │    │    └───g03
│    │    └───g02
│    └───g01
└───f11
    └───g11
```

Output(2):

```
folder1
│───folder2
│    └───folder3
│        │───file2
│        └───file3
└───folder3
    └───folder4
        │───file4
        └───file5
```

Output(3):

```
folder1
│───folder2
│   │───file1
│   │───file2
│   │───file3
│   │───file4
│   │───file5
│   │───file6
│   └───file7
│───file8
│───file9
│───folder3
│   │───file10
│   │───file11
│   └───file12
└───file13
```

Output(4):

```
folder1
│───file1
└───folder1
    └───file1
folder2
│───file2
└───folder3
    │───file3
    └───file4
```

Comment: @muw Can you post those other cases?

Comment: Here's a sample test case that doesn't output as expected:

[('folder1',), [('folder2',), 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6', 'file7'], 'file8', 'file9', [('folder3',), 'file10', 'file11', 'file12'], 'file13']

I forgot to mention that, when it's not yet the last element of the current folder, it should just print "├───". It will only print "└───" if it's the last element.

Comment: @muw Thank you for your edits, please see my recent update

Comment: It's working for Case 1 and 2, It's having some problems with higher level folders which is shown in Case 3.

Comment: Added a new Test Case 4 which tests higher level folders. The code you provided did not have the right output.

Comment: Will it be easier if we use dictionaries to sort these unique folders and files?

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for Case 4?

Comment: @muw Hey, I just saw your messages. I think your data structure is fine for folder representation purposes, I added a solution that will cover your new test case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223189/discussion-between-muw-and-ajax1234).

Comment: Hi, your updated code works, but I just noticed that it's not using ├ when there is a file/folder. It's supposed to print │if the file/folder is in another depth.

Also, The positions of folders and files are arbitrary, so there is a case that a folder inside a folder is in the 1st position and a file in the same folder is in the 2nd. I tried this case with your code and it did not work as expected.
well.

I posted a worst case.

Comment: Works fine as expected. One thing though, when I replace │ with ├, it puts ├ in some places where it's not supposed to be, can you point out where I'm supposed to put ├? I can't seem to replace it properly.

Comment: I was able to tweak your code with ├, but I noticed it only puts ├ for files, for folders, it prints │. I posted the result at the bottom of the question post.

Comment: Update, I made some configurations to your code, and it seems like all test cases are right. Thank you for your contribution! Latest code is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @muw Glad to help!